# SQL Server Parameters Make Dynamic Query Slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, dynamic, parameters

I ran into a weird problem caused by the parameters passed into dynamic SQL.

The dynamic SQL had parameters all through it like so:

```
SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (Book.ID = @paramBookID) ' 
IF (NOT @AuthorID IS NULL) 
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (Book.AuthorID = @paramAuthorID) '
```

And I then passed in the parameters to the sp_executeSql call like so:

```
-- Execute the parameterized dynamic SQL query
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(500) = N'@paramBookID int, @paramAuthorID int'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params,
    @paramBookID = @BookID,
    @paramAuthorID = @AuthorID
```

The dynamic query was very slow, and at first I thought it was the dynamic SQL execution that was causing the problem, so I created the dynamic SQL and copied it over to SSMS.
I then declared all the variables at the top of the query and it executed much faster (about a second, instead of 1+ minutes)
I then did some more fiddling around, and replaced a line where there was a variable with the actual value of the variable:

Replaced: AND (Book.AuthorID = @paramAuthorID)

With: AND (Book.AuthorID = 1471409)

The query started running slow again.
Not sure why this caused problems and made the query run so slow.
I even tried this:

AND (Book.AuthorID = CAST(1471409 AS INT))

because I thought maybe it was some sort of typing issue, but that didn’t help either, it still ran slow,
So in the end I ended up making a slight modification to the dynamic sql to copy all the parameters over into local variables in the dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = 
    N'DECLARE @BookId INT = @paramBookID ' +
    N'DECLARE @AuthorID INT = @paramAuthorID ' +
    @sql
```

The query now runs WAY faster, and I still have no explanation as to why. 
Does anyone have any insight into this weird solution I stumbled upon?

Comment: Keyword: `Parameter sniffing`

Comment: If it was caused by parameter sniffing does that mean that it will become slow again after the query has been used a bunch of times?

Comment: can you show the whole query? also the execution plans with dynamic sql and without the dynamic sql queries.

Comment: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html